# Redis pipeline usage

Tags: java, redis, pipeline, jedis, ttl

I'm trying to understand how pipeline works nad want to try something different. I've noticed that there's no method for setting expire key if the key doesn't have any so I made an example for that with Jedis.

**Example**

```
Map<String, Response> responses = new HashMap<>();

long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
try (Jedis resource = redisManager.getResource()) {

    Pipeline pipeline = resource.pipelined();

    responses.put("time", pipeline.ttl(args[1]));

    pipeline.sync();

    pipeline.multi();

    if (responses.get("time").get().equals(-1L)) {
        pipeline.expire(args[1], 15);
    }

    pipeline.exec();

}
```

I'd like to know that should I use like that or do you have any idea about it? I couldn't find any solution for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you sync and get the result after sending each command to the pipeline then there isn't much difference to sending the commands without pipelining. The benefit of pipelining comes from sending a number of commands without waiting on their responses and then reading the responses back all at once (thus eliminating a lot of time which would have been spent waiting for responses. More info: https://redis.io/topics/pipelining).

So a more "pipeline-y" implementation of what you have above would look like this (please pardon any mistakes with the exact pipeline method names, I mostly use Spring Data rather than straight Jedis):

```
List<String> keysToCheckForTtl = ...
Map<String, Response> responses = new HashMap<>();

for (String key : keysToCheckForTtl) {
  responses.put(key, pipeline.ttl(key));
}

pipeline.sync(); // get the responses back for all TTL commands

for (String key : keysToCheckForTtl) {
  if (responses.get(key).get().equals(-1L)) {
        pipeline.expire(key, 15);
  }
}

pipeline.exec(); // finalize all expire commands
```

As you can see, this works with a list of keys to check and expire. If you only need to check and then expire a single key, you don't need a pipeline.

Comment: I'll check a lot of keys then add TTL to multi key. Should I use like the example above?

Comment: I think something like that (do all the TTLs, get responses, do all expires) will work for you. It allows you to take advantage of the nature of pipelines by batching your commands as much as possible. Since you need the responses before you do the expires, I don't think it's possible to improve this by removing the one sync in the middle.

Comment: As I mention it this is the only way to solve it. I hope redis will add this feature soon.